# C++: Convert 2D array to 2D vector

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I would like to convert a 2D array (faces0) to a 2D vector (faces1). I tried the following code. It gives a compile time error.

```
bool read_polygon_mesh(Point_3 *points0,
    int **faces0,
    Polygon_mesh& polygon_mesh)
{
    std::vector<Point_3> points(points0, points0 + sizeof points0 / sizeof points0[0]);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> faces1(faces0, faces0 + sizeof faces0 / sizeof faces0[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof faces0 / sizeof faces0[0]; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> f(faces0[i], faces0[i] + sizeof faces0[i] / sizeof faces0[i][0]);
        faces1.push_back(f);
    }

    return read_polygon_mesh(points, faces1, polygon_mesh);
}
```

Edit: Maybe 2D array is not the correct expression when talking about faces0 because faces[0] can have a different number of elements than faces[1] etc. Please take this into consideration.

The error message I get is: 'std::vector<int,std::allocator>::vector': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

Also please take into consideration that I want to use this method in a DLL which I will call from a C# application, so I probably have to stick with C-style arrays.

I also tried interfacing with C# using the vectors but it yielded the error message that marshalling does not work with generic types:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DLLimport
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"region_growing_planes_on_polygon_mesh.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void region_growing1(List<Point_3> points, List<List<int>> faces1, string fullpath);

        class Point_3
        {
            double x, y, z;

            public Point_3(double x, double y, double z)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.z = z;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            region_growing1(
                new List<Point_3>() { new Point_3(10, 10, 10), new Point_3(20, 20, 10), new Point_3(30, 30, 10) }, 
                new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 } },
                "Scene-building-planes1.ply");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: `sizeof points0` is 8, as `points0` is a pointer.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Unless it's 2, 4 or 16 or ...

Comment: C has structs, you should pass them.

Comment: Looking at the inherent problems with the code I think the better solution is to create a vector in the first place, rather than attempt a conversion.

Comment: i think the original problem is that you are using `C` and `C++` and `C#` in the same project to begin with, mixing a lot of languages without a good knowledge of any of them will lead to bad designs for all of them, as you will always be making the worst decisions to get any code working, converting from an array to vector in this case is bad.

Comment: Pointers are not arrays, and arrays are not pointers. And `sizeof faces0 / sizeof faces0[0]` is the same as `sizeof(int**) / sizeof(int*)`.

Answer (score 1):

in your code `sizeof points0` is not the total size of the array, as `points0` is a pointer to the first element, not an array, instead you have to pass in the original array size to the function.

```cpp
bool read_polygon_mesh(Point_3 *points0, size_t num_points,
    int **faces0, size_t num_faces, size_t num_subfaces,
    Polygon_mesh& polygon_mesh)
{
    std::vector<Point_3> points(points0, points0 + num_points);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> faces1;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_faces; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> f(faces0[i], faces0[i] + num_subfaces);
        faces1.push_back(f);
    }

    return read_polygon_mesh(points, faces1, polygon_mesh);
}
```

this is obviously a bad design to pass `size_t` around, so consider using [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) of c++20 instead.

```cpp
struct faces_arr{
int** m_ptr;
size_t num_rows;
size_t num_cols;
};

bool read_polygon_mesh(std::span<Point_3> points0,
    faces_arr faces0,
    Polygon_mesh& polygon_mesh)
{
    std::vector<Point_3> points(points0.begin(), points0.end());
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> faces1;
    for (int i = 0; i < faces0.num_rows; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> f(faces0.m_ptr[i], faces0.m_ptr[i] + faces0.num_cols);
        faces1.push_back(f);
    }

    return read_polygon_mesh(points, faces1, polygon_mesh);
}
```

---

if the number of elements per row is different, then you need to store this information in a struct.

```
struct Point3_arr
{
Point_3* data;
size_t num_elements;
};

struct face
{
int* data;
size_t num_points;
};

struct faces_arr{
face* data;
size_t num_faces;
};

bool read_polygon_mesh(Point3_arr points0,
    faces_arr faces0,
    Polygon_mesh& polygon_mesh)
{
    std::vector<Point_3> points(points0.data, points0.data+ points0.num_elements);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> faces1;
    for (int i = 0; i < faces0.num_faces; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> f(faces0.data[i].data, faces0.data[i].data + faces0.data[i].num_points);
        faces1.push_back(f);
    }

    return read_polygon_mesh(points, faces1, polygon_mesh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "C" style arrays, but std::array and you can make a function template that will convert for you

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename type_t, std::size_t width_v, std::size_t height_v>
auto convert(const std::array<std::array<type_t,width_v>,height_v>& array_2d)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<type_t>> vector_2d(height_v,std::vector<type_t>(width_v));

    for(std::size_t row{0ul}; row < height_v; ++row)
    {
        for(std::size_t col{0ul}; col < width_v; ++col)
        {
            vector_2d[row][col] = array_2d[row][col];
        }
    }

    return vector_2d;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int,3>,2> array_2d {{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}};
    auto vector_2d = convert(array_2d);

    for(const auto& row : vector_2d)
    {
        for(const auto& value : row)
        {
            std::cout << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```